# Unit hyperspheres in different spaces

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations, spheres, spherical-geometry

Let $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a matrix. So a unit hypersphere in the original space does not become a unit hypersphere in the $L$-transformed space. But is this similar to a unit hypersphere in the $L$-transformed space. So do they have the same shape in this space?

Thank you very much!!!

Comment: What do you mean by "same shape?"

Comment: Draw some examples in the plane when $n = 2$..

Comment: _Shape_ is not a property of a point set alone, but of a set equipped with additional structure, such as a topological metric or a Riemannian metric. As stated, it's hard to know what you're asking: (i) Is "the original space" Cartesian $n$-space, or Euclidean $n$-space? (ii) Do you mean anything specific by "similar to"? (iii) What is the "$L$-transformed space", Cartesian or Euclidean? (iv) As William asks, what do you mean by "do they have the same shape in this space?" Could you please nounify your pronouns?

Comment: So i am working on this paper: https://www.researchgate.net/publication/271833345_A_Uniformly_Distributed_Random_Portfolio . 
And i'm thinking about this statement for a matric $L$: "A unit hypersphere in the original space does not become a unit hypersphere in the $L$-transformed space. However. [...] considering a unit hypersphere in a $L$-transformed space does not affect our analysis." The further analysis is based on the ratio of the surface area of ​​a hypersperical cap of a unit hypersphere and the surface area of ​​the unit hypersphere in the $L$-transformed space.

Comment: So the question is whether this ratio of the transformed unit hypersphere is equal to the ratio of the unit hypersphere in the $L$-transformed space. 
That's what I meant by similar and same shape. Unfortunately, I don't know whether the space is Eulidean or Cartesian. 
Thank you very much for your support!

Comment: So the space is Euclidean.